# Ending target early in Phing

Tags: build, phing

I am trying to modify a Phing script and cannot see what I thought would be an obvious feature.

The Phing script has a generic 'confirm' target which checks for input at various stages of execution. I want to automate the script so that it can run without input. I would expect to be able to to this by inserting some kind of `<break>` or `<end>` type task within the target so that it returns early. The [manual](https://www.phing.info/docs/stable/hlhtml/index.html) does't appear to list such functionality.

I know I can achieve this, by creating an intermediate target to check the cmd line argument first and then call the confirm target, but is there a more elegant way?

This is the target that needs automating and is called from multiple places. The trigger to skip would be a property set via cmd line -D.

```
 <!-- confirm a user action -->
<target name="confirm">
    <input propertyname="confirm" validargs="yes,no">
        ${confirm.message} ('yes' to continue)
    </input>
    <if>
        <not>
            <equals arg1="${confirm}" arg2="yes" />
        </not>
        <then>
            <fail message="You didn't say 'yes'" />
        </then>
    </if>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same purpose I'm using this tech:

```
<if>
  <not>
    <isset property="confirm" />
  </not>
  <then>
    <input propertyname="confirm" validargs="yes,no">
        ${confirm.message} ('yes' to continue)
    </input>
    <if>
        <not>
            <equals arg1="${confirm}" arg2="yes" />
        </not>
        <then>
            <fail message="You didn't say 'yes'" />
        </then>
    </if>
  </then>
</if>
```

then you can execute

```
phing build.xml -Dconfirm=yes
```

without promt.